# Filter rows with incorrect date

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the dataset below, how can I find/filter the rows with incorrect and no (`NA`) date values in the `Request Date` column?

Basically the correct dates will be something like, for example, `1/01/2022` or `11/01/2022`.

[Actual data](https://app.box.com/s/k7s0e6imjr65u1f8olxzeitd0pagwlmv)

**Data**:

```
structure(list(Year = c("2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", 
"2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022"), `Reference Number` = c("14784", 
"14784", "14785", "14785", "14786", "14786", "14787", "14787", 
"14788", "14788"), `Request Date` = c("1/6/2022", "1/6/2022", 
"11/19/2022", "Happy New Year", "1899-12-31 02:40:00", "Ongoing", "1//12/05", 
"01/14/205", "1/25/20`22", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Code**:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = df %>% filter() #.... stuck
```

Comment: `select` is used to get needed columns, while for needed rows, you use `filter` or `slice`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `anytime::anytime` fucntion:

```
df %>% filter(is.na(anytime::anytime(`Request Date`)))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  Year  `Reference Number` `Request Date`
  <chr> <chr>              <chr>         
1 2022  14785              Happy New Year
2 2022  14787              1//12/05      
3 2022  14787              01/14/205     
4 2022  14788              1/25/20`22    
5 2022  14788              NA
```

Comment: The function `anytime` crashes `R Studio` with error stating `R Session Aborted`. Please note that my dataset has `6694` rows, I don't know if that's causing the crash.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy try using `coalesce(ymd(date), dmy(date), mdy(date), dmy_hms(date))`

Comment: Is `date` = `Request Date`?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy yes. Include all the formats you can think of in the coalesce function. Then get those that are NA. There should be a `parse_date` function that has formats argument but can't recal the package

Comment: @Ed_Gravy use `parse_date_time` function with all the necessary orders

Comment: should I use `coalesce` as df %>%filter(coalesce(ymd(`Request Date`), dmy(`Request Date`), mdy(`Request Date`), dmy_hms(`Request Date`))) ?

Comment: If using coalesce use filter(is.na(coalesce(....))) or filter(is.na(parse_date_time(date, ...))) with all the orders you want

Comment: I am sorry but I am still having problems. I know it's not best practise but since my dataset is too big to paste here I have uploaded it on box.com and added a link to the question. Hopefully this will help, thank you.

Comment: Master of the mystic art ;)

Comment: When I run `coalesce` I get this error Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = is.na(...)`.
Caused by error in `gsub()`:
! input string 3 is invalid UTF-8

Comment: And with `parse_date` I get Warning: 5666 parsing failures.
row col   expected    actual
  1  -- date like  1/6/2022

Comment: @Ed_Gravy i did not try those 2. They were an option i would consider. In the case for `anytime`, you can consider doing the work in batches of either 1000 or even 500